# Get tortoisesvn to give me filenames with build number in the filename

Tags: windows-7, svn, tortoise-svn

I am on a Windows 7 box, and I have tortoisesvn on my machine. After getting a little familiar with svn and tortoisesvn on a code repository, I set up a local repository to manage revisions of some word and powerpoint documents.

I want to figure out some scripted way to output a set of files with the build/revision number embedded in the filename. I will then email the files to some business people to review.

For example, say I have a group of files in my working directory:

```
PresentA.pptx
PresentA-notes.docx
PresentB.pptx
```

and TortoiseSVN repo browser tells me that I am currently at revision 21 for `PresentA.pptx` and `PresentA-notes.docx` but at revision 25 for `PresentB.pptx`, I would like some way to get 3 files with the following names:

```
PresentA-r21.pptx
PresentA-notes-r21.docx
PresentB-r25.pptx
```

Alternatively, if revision 25 is the current value for the repository, having all the names appended with `-r25` would work, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html).

It may do what I need, but I don't really know enough about Windows BATCH scripting (or that new Windows Powershell) to glue [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) together with a file rename.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken, do you know of an alternative link?

Comment: Fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [grepwin](http://code.google.com/p/grepwin/) will do what what is needed?

> grepWin is a simple search and replace tool which can use regular expressions to do its job. This allows to do much more powerful searches and replaces.

[image]